# How can I bonsai a pin oak?

Tags: bonsai, oak

I have a small [pin oak](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quercus_palustris) in a small pot thriving since spring in Brooklyn. I would like to keep it and I am thinking about bonsai. I think I need to keep it outside for two years? Should I give it a bigger pot now? It's in a lame pot from a medium size tomato plant from Home Depot. I have no experience with bonsai other than a noted attraction to the art.

Answer (score 1):

I tried some bonsai techniques on burr oak seedlings ([Quercus macrocarpa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quercus_macrocarpa)). The issues I encountered when I tried to achieve a classic bonsai were:

- leaves did not reduce in proportion to the trunk.  If you have a trunk as thick as a straw and leaves as long as your finger it does not look right.
- trunk did not thicken and look interesting unless a rabbit ate the top in the winter
- as a deciduous tree it required a cold period so I had to heel them into a trench every fall and dig them out in the spring

I have seen some impressive bonsai that were two feet tall with thick trunks but they were a hundred years old.  To get an oak to look good was going to take twenty or thirty years.

Nonetheless you can have fun with it.

- Provide a sheltered place for the winter with protection from rabbits.
- I had great success with installing a [capillary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capillary_action) wick in the root ball that trailed out of the pot into a water feature.  No watering problems!